# How to flatten and transpose an array in AppsScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a custom Google Spreadsheets function in AppsScript that will take an array ("range") of arbitrary dimensions and return the unique values in a single column. The function takes an optional argument `transpose` that should sort the output by rows instead of columns.

I've got this semi-working, but the `transpose` method is only working on square arrays:

```js
function GETUNIQUES(range, transpose) {
  traspose = transpose || !0;
  if (transpose) {
    range = range.map(function(col, i) {
      return range.map(function(row) {
        return row[i];
      });
    });
  }
  
  var flat = [];
  var clean = [];
  for (i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < range[i].length; j++) {
      flat.push(range[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    flat[i] = String(flat[i]);
    if (flat[i].length && clean.indexOf(flat[i].trim()) < 0) {
      clean.push(flat[i].trim());
    }
  }
  return clean;
}
```

Could someone help me with a solution for the `transpose` method that follows row order without truncating results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose does not work with [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), because the length could be not the wanted length.

Transpose with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var range = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]];

range = function (array) {
    var r = [];
    array.forEach(function (a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || [];
            r[j][i] = b;
        });
    });
    return r;
}(range);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Transpose with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var range = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]];

range = range.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    a.forEach(function (b, j) {
        r[j] = r[j] || [];
        r[j][i] = b;
    });
    return r;
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(range, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

*from the [Sheets Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2gtgHexEe5o):*

> `=ARRAYFORMULA({array1;array2;array3})`

...will merge multiple ranges in one view-only column then:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A5; B3:B7; C10}))
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A5; B3:B7; C10})))
```